# Cosmos DB EF ReadItemAsync exception occurs Response status code does not indicate success: Unauthorized (401);

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The command I'm executing:

`var feature = await container.ReadItemAsync<CosmosNormalizedFeatureModel>(guid, new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.PartitionKey(partitionKey));`

Throws an exception:

`Response status code does not indicate success: Unauthorized (401); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: ; Reason: ();`

I don't believe this is true, but I don't see anything wrong either.

- when I use `GetItemLinqQueryable` I have no issues connecting to Cosmos
- I've verified the partition key exists + set to correct property and returns data
- I've verified the guid/id exists and returns data
- I've verified the container is set to the correct container
- Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.20.1

Not sure what else I can check to troubleshoot the issue. Thanks!

Stack trace

```
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.ProcessMessage[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage, Func`2 createResponse)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosResponseFactoryCore.CreateItemResponse[T](ResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.<ReadItemAsync>d__56`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.<RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync>d__38`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.<OperationHelperWithRootTraceAsync>d__29`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at xxx.<GetFeatureByGuid>d__7.MoveNext() in D:\xxx.cs:line 183
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at xxx.<GetNormalizedILIReportFeatureByGuid>d__10.MoveNext() in D:\xxx.cs:line 280
```

Comment: Unauthorized errors are described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-unauthorized
Are you working on a real account or the Emulator?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta a real account, I don't see anything related to MAC signatures in the error message and I can execute `GetItemLinqQueryable` perfectly fine

Comment: It is certainly odd, 401 is often a response from the service. Are you using Resource Tokens?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta currently using account keys

Comment: I would then go with a support case, like I said, 401 is a response from the service. Could you maybe share a full exception stack trace or details here? Maybe the full stack trace/details reveal something we are missing.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta sure thing I added the stack trace, I'll open a ticket. thanks for looking

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of is clock skew, basically the machine clock is off so the signature is invalid. Normally this is seen when you call ToString on the exception.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I figured it out, I guess it requires a read/write key. Read key does not work which seems odd....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments - you are using [Bulk mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/).

When using Bulk mode, operations are packed together to improve network performance (the operation type is not relevant, read operations can be packed with write operations) and sent as a single payload to the backend.

The payload is of a different type calling a different API (so the backend can unpack them and process them and return a packed response).

This API uses the Write keys (because inside the package there could be any type of operation). The fact that you are using the Read-only keys is what is causing the 401. Ideally the backend should be more explicit in the error it returns though.

Answer (score 1):

The key being used to connect to cosmos is a read key, it appears that the point read requires a read/write key.

Comment: Are you using Bulk mode enabled?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta yes it is

Comment: That is the cause, see the answer

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta is there a reason why `GetItemLinqQueryable` does not throw the same error?

Comment: Because Bulk affects point operations: Create,Upsert,Replace,Read item. Queries cannot be executed through Bulk.